# What card is missing?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Once you figure out the pattern, the rest will follow suit:

[image: image created by me]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing cards are

> [image] and [image]

Because

> They are Braille and spell `BLACK JACK`

Comment: I'm impressed that you made images for this! Alternatively, the cards are: [card 1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack_of_clubs) and [card 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack_of_spades) (in no particular order).

Answer (score 3):

The missing cards are:

> **X.**
>  **..**
>  **X.**
>  and
>  **XX**
>  **..**
>  **..**
>  where X represents a circle and a period represents a blank space.

This is because:

> The cards are braille, spelling out BLACK and 0123 respectively.